# exceptions in java using inheritance

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

i am a new in java .please help me . i want to implement exception using inheritance . i want to make a super class say ExceptionA and two sub classes ExceptionB and ExceptionC . i want to write a program that catches exception with super class.ExceptionB class inherit from ExceptionA class and ExceptionC class inherit form ExceptionB.i also want that my code must demonstrate that the catch block for type ExceptionA catches exceptions of types ExceptionB and ExceptionC.
i try my best but in vain.code is here

```
package assignment.solution;
```

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */

```
 public class ExceptionA {
    //code for Arithmetic eception
        public static void method2() throws ArithmeticException{
        int x=4;
        int y=0;
       int z=x/y;
    }

    public static void method1(){
        try{
            method2();
        }
    catch(ArithmeticException ex){
       System.out.println("divide by zero occured");
    }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExceptionA.method1();


    }

}
 class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA{
   // i want to show here that catch block of parent class work here 

 }
    catch (ArithmeticException eex){

    super.method1();
 }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what your Problem is

Comment: You should post a code example because that is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: What have you tried already? You can't expect that we'll write it for you. Show what you have, and we'll try to help you fix it up.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. It is obviously hard to understand.

Comment: You are also new to this site. Please spend some time at the [help] to understand why you receive such negative feedback. And then: read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

All exception in Java belongs to the superclass Exceptions.
In order to create an exception class, you must create a class which extends the super class.

```
class MyException extends Exception{ 
 }
```

Now if you want another class that inherits MyException. Well, you simply declare a new class that extends MyException.

```
class MyException2 extends MyException{ 
     }
```